# nth-of-type: all but n

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering if there's a way to apply css/jquery to all but the nth element.

I'm guessing I could just set a css to apply to all elements, and then undo that css with the nth element:

```
li {
    background-color: green
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: white
}
```

But is there a way to do this directly with one statement?

Comment: `:not(:nth-of-type(1))`? Actually, in this case: `:nth-of-type(n+1)` should do it (or possibly +2  can't remember)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, that would be `:nth-child(n+2)` (`n` takes all integer values starting from 0), but using `:not(...)` is better, since it can be used when *n* is not 1.

Answer (score 8):

Use `:not()`:

```
li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    background-color: white
}
```

Comment: and [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility)